# TypeError: _() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have an error, which appears after I run my script in Databricks

> TypeError: _() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

```
sessionevents = eventsDF.filter(eventsDF.eventcategory.contains("size guide","native size guide","product interactions")).groupby('eventcategory','uniquesessionid').count()
```

I am not sure if I should in this case define the self and if yes then how. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Column` method [`contains`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html) can only take one value but you're passing 3. The function is defined as:

> def contains(self, item: Any) -> Column

The errors message says "2 positional arguments" as it counts `self` which is the Column itself.

If I correctly understood what you're trying to achieve, you can use `rlike` function instead:

```
sessionevents = eventsDF.filter(
       eventsDF.eventcategory.rlike("size guide|native size guide|product interactions")
   ).groupby('eventcategory', 'uniquesessionid').count().show()
```